# Can't add a mitmproxy .p12 certificate to Windows programmatically

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, man-in-the-middle, mitmproxy

I want to programmatically install certificate into Windows for localhost MITM SSL sniffing.

```
>certutil -addstore "TrustedPublisher" mitmproxy-ca-cert.p12
TrustedPublisher
CertUtil: -addstore команда НЕ ВЫПОЛНЕНА: 0x80093102 (ASN: 258)
CertUtil: В ASN1 встречен неожиданный конец данных.
```

means in English the `Unexpected end of data`
While this command:

```
>certutil -asn \Users\Nakilon\.mitmproxy\mitmproxy-ca-cert.p12
CertUtil: -asn - команда успешно выполнена.
```

doesn't see any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [convert](http://p12pem.com/) .p12 cert to .pem and then you will be able to import it through your command.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/certinstall.html:

```
 certutil.exe -importpfx Root mitmproxy-ca-cert.p12
```